# My electrical switchboard is making this continuous chirping noise

Tags: circuit-breaker

In the main circuit breaker switchboard I have this continuous chirping noise. It chirps 3-4 times a seconds. It's not very loud. But you can hear it from the room where this switch board stands (kitchen in my case).

Here is a **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWiyjB_gnIw)** I made.

[image: Switch Board]

What is the reason for this noise? Is it a warning sign? Can something bad happen very soon?

Comment: A car alarm? A power supply with very poor hick-up? What’s inside it more than breakers?

Comment: Turn off breakers until you figure out which breaker chirps. Then figure out what load on that breaker might draw current in a way that causes chirping.

Comment: @Justme If you have seen the video, I have turned off all the breakers except the red and the adjacent one.

Comment: Household electrics(switches lights, panels) should not make noise.  Turn off the ones still on and see if the noise goes away.  If still have noise turn off the main breaker/switch for the house.  If noise is still there then probably have mice, bugs, birds in the wall.  If noise goes away, get an electrician to check.

Comment: Do you have a burglar alarm or a smoke detector nearby, perhaps? Could its battery be low?

Comment: There is a smoke detector. But I know it's alarm sound as I have replaced the battery a year ago. And there is no burglar alarm.

Comment: Right next to the main breaker I see an RCD.  I notice you didn't turn either one off in the video.  Why not?  If the sound doesn't stop with the main shut off, you can exclude this whole panelboard.  An RCD is the one thing in a panel I might imagine would have an audible alarm ("I have failed my internal self-test and can no longer provide protection, replace me").

Answer (score 3):

That's not a chirp, it's a siren.

It is louder towards the bottom of the box.

Something inside (or below) the breaker box is trying to tell you that something is wrong.

Potential sources:

1. UPS
2. Alarm system (smoke/fire or burglar alarm.)  It may also be just the alarm system power supply that is installed in the breaker box.
3. Other devices installed in the breaker box.  The stickers on your breaker box mention telecommunications - there may be some kind of DSL modem or other device installed in your breaker box.

What to do:

- Check all known devices in and around the breaker box for proper function.
- If you can't find the source, ask an electrician to look inside the covered panels of the breaker box to see if there is some device hidden inside.
- If this is in a rented house or appartment, contact the landlord before calling in an electrician.  The landlord may know what the problem is or may have a preferred electrician to call.

Comment: This is good observation that the sound is lower at the bottom. I'll record the sound in different places.